# Add babel-polyfill by default?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I created a boilerplate to use babel's `async`/`await` and you need a polyfill to use it.

Here's the repo https://github.com/reggi/esnext-boilerplate

Here's an example:

```
import "babel-polyfill"

async function five() {
  return 5
}

async function helloWorld() {
  var numb = await five()
  console.log(numb)
}

helloWorld() // logs `5`
```

Is there any way for babel to automatically compile with `babel-polyfill` so I don't need to explicitly import it?

Answer (score 2):

`babel-polyfll` can be preloaded with webpack if you set your entry to both the `babel-polyfll` module and the root of your bundle.

```
entry: ["babel-polyfill", "src/index.js"]
```